# JAX-RS 2.0 Filter parameters via @NameBinding annotation

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I've created some JAX-RS 2.0 resources (using Jeresey 2.4 running in a Servlet container) and a filter that handles authentication and authorisation that can be selectively applied via a @NameBinding annotation. This all works great.

I would like to be able to define some parameters on this annotation (specifically, security permissions that are required to access each method/resource) that can be available to the filter at runtime to alter this behaviour.

I notice that interceptors can do this via javax.ws.rs.ext.InterceptorContext.getAnnotations() but there is no equivalent in javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext for filters. Any ideas how this may be achieved? I would like to be able to do something like the following:

```
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@NameBinding
public @interface Secured {
    String[] requiredPermissions() default {};
}

@Secured
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class SecurityRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException {
        // extract credentials, verify them and check that the user has required permissions, aborting if not
    }
}

@Path("/userConfiguration/")
public class UserConfigurationResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    @Secured(requiredPermissions = {"configuration-permission"})
    public Response getConfig(@Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        // produce a response
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For a non-vendor specific solution, since JAX-RS 2.0 you can use [`ResourceInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceInfo.html):

```
@Secured
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class SecurityRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        Method method = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod();

        if (method != null) {
            Secured secured = method.getAnnotation(Secured.class);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can get this information from [UriInfo](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html), particularly it's (Jersey specific) [ExtendedUriInfo](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ExtendedUriInfo.html) subinterface. To obtain an instance either invoke [ContainerRequestContext#getUriInfo()](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html#getUriInfo%28%29) and cast it

```
final ExtendedUriInfo extendendUriInfo = (ExtendedUriInfo) containerRequestContext.getUriInfo();
```

or inject it into your filter:

```
@Inject
private ExtendedUriInfo extendendUriInfo;
```

then

```
extendedUriInfo
    .getMatchedResourceMethod()
    .getInvocable()
    .getHandlingMethod().getAnnotation(Secured.class);
```

In the second approach you can implement [DynamicFeature](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/DynamicFeature.html) and assign your filter only to a particular resource methods (i.e. in case the configuration of the filter is more complex, filter applies only to a couple of methods and you want to reduce the overhead, ...). Take a look at the implementation of [RolesAllowedDynamicFeature](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/filter/RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.java) which adds support for security annotations over resource methods in Jersey.

Comment: Thanks, this solves things (although of course it would be nice if this could be done in a more generic way without resorting to Jersey-specific APIs).

Regarding RolesAllowedDynamicFeature, this would mean implementing all this in a SecurityContext... I've tried this but since many things that our SSO solution supports (e.g. step-up authentication) are hard to express I'm ignoring all standard authentication APIs and just adding it as a layer on top.

Comment: To be clear: I won't be using this; there's only a handful of permissions I need to check, so I've created an absract filter and just subclass it (and define a @NameBinding) for each permission. Bit of boilerplate but it also means I can define the permissions in runtime config instead of hard-coding them as annotation params. Still, good to know this is possible.