# How to access JAX-RS Application impl. from Filter?

Tags: annotations, glassfish, jersey, jax-rs

I've created JAX-RS `@NameBinding` annotation:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@NameBinding
public @interface EnableMyFilter {
    @Nonbinding
    String value() default "";
}
```

and use this to activate filter, which checks value of `@EnableMyFilter` annotation. This part is crucial to me, as creating separate annotations and filters would produce much of boilerplate code. Filter code:

```
@Provider
@EnableMyFilter
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        final ExtendedUriInfo extendendUriInfo = (ExtendedUriInfo) requestContext.getUriInfo();

        Method method = extendendUriInfo.getMatchedResourceMethod().getInvocable().getHandlingMethod();
        RestrictedEnvironment annotation = method.getAnnotation(EnableMyFilter.class); // get method-level annotation
        if (annotation == null) {
            annotation = method.getDeclaringClass().getAnnotation(EnableMyFilter.class); // get class-level annotation
            if (annotation == null) {
                // here application-level annotation should be get
            }
        }

        // do something with annotation value...
    }
}
```

As you may see, I'm using Jersey specific ExtendedUriInfo to reflect method and get annotation (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19798751/2512304)), and if it fails, get annotation from class. But `@NameBinding` can be done also on application-level, e.g.:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
@EnableMyFilter("some-val")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
}
```

and with this application class provider will also be triggered - which is 100% good. But how can I get this class annotations in filter()?

I've tried to inject `@Context`

```
@Context
private Application application;
```

but `application.getClass().toString()` returns `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$WrappingResourceConfig` (what I understand) with no annotations.

I'm working on Glassfish 4.1 build 13, Java 8.

Comment: If you need some arbitrary application level configuration value, maybe just set a configuration property, and inject [`Configuration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Configuration.html) to get the value. You can override `public Map<String, Object> getProperties()` in the `Application` class. The values in that map will be available in the `Configuration`

Comment: @peeskillet As [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/NameBinding.html) says NameBinding annotation can be attached to Application subclass. I want to make lib for JAX-RS extension, to manage app security, environment settings and more. So your suggestions do not apply here.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the link. I'm not sure I see the point of it, as not annotating the resources will cause the filter to be used anyway. In any case, are you saying the using the explicit `RestApplication.class` will not work? Can you give an example of why it would not. I'm trying to get a better understanding of what it is you're trying to do exactly

Comment: Nevermind. I think I see what you're saying. This library will not include the `RestApplication` class, am I right? It's just an example of a class some user of your library will create. Am I correct?

Comment: I don't know. I've been playing around with this idea, and a couple ways I can see it working if either the user explicitly defines the class as a configuration property or if you scan the classpath (on load) and look for the Application subclass, and add it yourself as a configuration property. You might offer an optimization to explicitly define the Application subclass as a configuration property

Comment: As an aside, you can inject the JAX-RS standard `ResourceInfo`, if you don't want to tie this lib to Jersey. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29201811/2587435)

Comment: So it looks like there is no easy way to achieve this. It's sad. But thank you for the ideas and for link about using ResourceInfo.